# Wordpress woocommerce Cart Shortcode not loading correctly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Hi everyone I have this woocommerce shortcode on my category page

```
<div id="za_left">

<h2>Wöchentlich</h2>
<div id="za_list">[product_category category="woechentlich" per_page="55" columns="1" orderby="date" order="desc"]</div>
<div id="za_right">
[woocommerce_cart]
</div>
```

This brings up the list of products and the cart which is empty at the start.
Now on the **first click** the item is added to the cart, but the shortcode is not updating the cart, so it shows it is still empty.

[image]

So the cart on the right side is not reloading/refreshing.
After I refresh the page it is showing the cart and I can add product like it should be.

How can I refresh the cart or reload the div, without reloading the page?
Maybe someone came across a similar problem. The cart is with ajax enabled.

You can visit
http://lesezirkel-westermann.de/wordpress/zeitschriftenauswahl/
to see this issue, please note that the left side is not css'ed right now.

**Edit1:**
I found a solution. cart-empty.php is loaded when the cart is empty, which is okay, but this php file doesn't give the oppotunity to load item into the cart.

So I copied the content from cart.php to cart-empty.php and it is now working. not a nice solution though.

Maybe someone finds a better one.

Comment: Is it single product page ?

Comment: No its a page, with a product categorie

Comment: If you are in hurry and don't able to find solution, I can give you a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the woocommerce with some other pre-installed theme like 2012 or some other

Please review the below link

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cart-widget-not-updating-in-woocommerce-201

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-update-cart-button-not-working

Comment: Iam using Theme Twenty Twelve, and found no answers in those two links

Answer (score 0):

You can load the any specific div on DOM. Whenever the add to cart button trigger then refresh the particular div in which your cart is like

> $("#yourSidebarCartDIv").load('YourUrl');

OR

> $("#yourSidebarCartDIv").load(location.href + " #yourSidebarCartDIv");

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to achieve desire result is, use **in built** `cart` form of the woocommerce.

So your your **code** would be something like this :

```
    <div id="za_left">

    <h2>Wöchentlich</h2>
    <div id="za_list"><?php echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="woechentlich" per_page="55" columns="1" orderby="date" order="desc"]') ?></div>
    <div class="woocommerce">
    <?php
    wc_print_notices();

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

    <table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-price"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ) ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                            <?php
                                $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                                    echo $thumbnail;
                                else
                                    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $thumbnail );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name">
                            <?php
                                if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                else
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                // Meta data
                                echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                                // Backorder notification
                                if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) )
                                    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . __( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-quantity">
                            <?php
                                if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                    $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                                } else {
                                    $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                        'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                        'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                        'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                                        'min_value'   => '0'
                                    ), $_product, false );
                                }

                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' );
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                    <?php if ( WC()->cart->coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                        <div class="coupon">

                            <label for="coupon_code"><?php _e( 'Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php _e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_coupon'); ?>

                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" name="proceed" value="<?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>

    </form>

    <?php //do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Simply just **paste** it.

Let me know the output.

Comment: I tried this before. But after saving and reloading the page, I get a blank one. After looking into the code there are several errors, like $_product->get_title() can not be used.

Comment: Can you apply code and then share its output with me /